# Who can explain this ajax code for me

Tags: ajax

Who can explain this code on the left for me, thanks!
I don't understand
Someone can explain it for me?

[Ajax:](http://www.44lan.cn/lan_browser/ajax/tryyourselef.aspx?x=ajax_first)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// 兼容 IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// 兼容 IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>让 AJAX 改变这段文本</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">改变内容</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wish you could teach japanese to me :)

Comment: This tutorial can explain: [link]http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: Nothing special about the code. Just look at any AJAX tutorial for an explanation.

Comment: Whoa, Chinese W3Schools clone.

Answer (score 2):

If i am not wrong, it will listen to the button and in the var xmlhttp; makes the request.
`xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` check if request finished and response is ready and == 200 see if status is "OK". if all is true in the if condition goes to the div with id "myDiv" and makes and append to with the request from this. The request is just the content from the file `ajax_info.txt`.

Hope it helps and you will understand :)

Comment: Thank you.I was just a beginner.sorry,I need more time to pratice ajax.